# sum two rows in a table

Tags: sql, view

1. I have a table view **'companyshares'** which has two columns **'companyname'**
   and **'shares'** in SQL.
2. I want the sum of 2 or more rows of **'companyshares'**.
3. The condition of summing is that they would get
   summed only if **'companyname'** is same on 2 or more records.
4. The rows which are summed must be shown as a row along with all
   the other data.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to search for a way doing this or you just posted here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select companyname, sum(shares) as shares
from companyshares
group by companyname
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dude.. It was easy though.. I was confused after writing this query to show the first table (on image above)..

`SELECT company_PR.Comp_name, user_shares_purchase.Shares_Qty_Pur 
   FROM company_PR INNER JOIN user_shares_purchase 
   ON company_PR.Comp_ID = user_shares_purchase.Comp_ID_US 
   WHERE Person_ID_US = (SELECT Person_ID FROM user_register WHERE Username ='"+ username.text +"');`

Then, I Summed both @juergen d and above code.

`SELECT company_PR.Comp_name as CompanyName, SUM(user_shares_purchase.Shares_Qty_Pur) as Shares 
   FROM company_PR INNER JOIN user_shares_purchase 
   ON company_PR.Comp_ID = user_shares_purchase.Comp_ID_US 
   WHERE Person_ID_US = (SELECT Person_ID from user_register where Username ='"+ username.text +"') 
   GROUP BY company_PR.Comp_name;`

Thank you...